# Converting Regular Expressions For Use With VBA

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Forgive me if this seems basic, but I'm new to regular expressions, and I can't seem to find general information that isn't example driven.

Basically, I'd like to know what to keep in mind when converting regular expressions found around the internet for use with vba. Is it as simple as "oh, just change the non-greedy operator to this ...", or is it involved on a level that I really need to find VBA specific expressions, or get better at writing my own.

My specific example involves converting this phone number pattern

```
^((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

But i'm really more interested in either a general approach, or an affirmation of its futility. Thanks!

Comment: This really depends on what you mean by "expressions found around the internet." In general, though, .NET expressions (of which I believe VBA expressions are a subset) are fairly comprehensive, unlike, say, Javascript, which doesn't support lookbehind assertions. As long as you're not carrying over super-complex Perl expressions, I don't think you'll need to make any modifications. (But watch out for modifiers like multi-line mode; and also note in some languages like Java, regular expression strings are escaped such that backslashes are doubled, etc.)

Comment: To answer your question more specifically, the above phone number expression will work as expected in VBA.

Comment: The real answer is probably "get better at writing your own", or at least get to the point where you can better understand what's going on in a regex found on the web. Here's a good reference for vbscript: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx

Comment: @acheong87 Regular Expressions 5.5 (the one usually used with VBA) is actually more like Javascript regex. E.g. it doesn't have negative/positive lookbehinds (the main feature lacking), it doesn't have named grouping and so on

Comment: You basically have no choice but to read through the reg exp, in conjunction with a syntax regerence (though you can probably understand most of it without any reference, if you understand VBA reg exp) and 'translate' it to VBA syntax. Some things will not be able to translated, as most 'regular expressions' libraries actually do a lot more and have their own features. E.g. Negative lookbehinds will be a no-go. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x.aspx for a basic syntax guide.

Comment: For an overview of differences between regex flavours I'd recommend this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html note that VBA is not listed there, but .NET is close enough probably.

Comment: Test your stuff out on <http://regexpal.com/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on Cor_Blimey and funkwurm's comments, I have used VBScript 5.5 regexes in Office 2003 and Office 2007 VBA with good success.  Details [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vb.html).  For anything more complicated than () and [] groups, I have found writing from scratch more effective than trying to modify an existing expression.